# How to get big amount of data as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to return an array of constructed objects that are build on top of objects that I retrieve from some url plus another fields that I get from another url.
I have an array that consists of two arrays that each has about 8000 objects...
I have tried to make each object construction as a thread however it still takes a lot of time...
Any solution? Here is my code:

```
def get_all_players_full_data(ea_players_json):
    all = []
    ea_players_json = list(ea_players_json.values())
    for i in range(len(ea_players_json)):
        for player_obj in ea_players_json[i]:
            all.append(player_obj)

     for player_obj in range(len(all)):
        all_data = []
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(len(all)) as executor:
            for player_data in all:
                future = executor.submit(build_full_player_data_obj, player_data)
                print(future.result())
                all_data.append(future.result())

def build_full_player_data_obj(ea_player_data):
    if ea_player_data.get("c") is not None:
        player_full_name = ea_player_data.get("c")
    else:
        player_full_name = ea_player_data.get("f") + " " + ea_player_data.get("l")
    player_id = ea_player_data.get("id")
    # go to futhead to find all cards of that player
    futhead_url_player_data = f'{FUTHEAD_PLAYER}{player_full_name}'
    details_of_specific_player = json.loads(requests.get(futhead_url_player_data).content)

    cards_from_the_same_id = []
    for player_in_json_futhead in details_of_specific_player:
        if player_in_json_futhead["player_id"] == player_id:
            rating = player_in_json_futhead["rating"]
            specific_card_id = player_in_json_futhead["def_id"]
            revision = player_in_json_futhead["revision_type"]
            name = player_in_json_futhead["full_name"]
            nation = player_in_json_futhead["nation_name"]
            position = player_in_json_futhead["position"]
            club = player_in_json_futhead["club_name"]
            cards_from_the_same_id.append(Player(specific_card_id, name, rating, revision, nation, 
            position, club))
     return cards_from_the_same_id
```

Comment: You need to understand where the time is being spent.  Apparently you download thousands of data items from various urls.  How long does that take?  Even if your python code executes instantly, you will never be able to overcome that.

Comment: It takes more than 2 hours haha !!!!

Comment: Unrelated, but the you can replace the entire loop in `build_full_player_data_obj` with `cards_from_the_same_id = [Player(*f(x)) for x in detail_of_specific_player if x["player_id"] == player_id]` where `f = operator.itemgetter("def_id", "full_name", "rating", "revision_type", "nation_name", "position", "club_name")`.

Comment: what does this syntax means ? And what about my question-Am I using thread s correctly ?

Comment: Are you saying that it takes 2 hours just to download the data?  Do you understand why? Data transfer by a network is mostly done by the operating system. With a fast internet connection you could download gigabytes of data in that amount of time.  Until you figure that out, you are wasting your time trying to optimize your Python code.

Comment: I am not downloading anything .. I have two json files ... I want to loop over all their objects and construct new ones that consist  of the properties of both to a new obj.That construction takes 2 hours, not downloading

Comment: Your build_full_player_data_obj function is O(n) when it could be O(1) by having an indexed structure by player_id. That means you are needlessly slowing down your code by roughly a factor of 4000. Fixing this algorithmically is a lot more realistic than brute forcing with threads, which may actually degrade your performance due to cache trashing and the Gil.

Comment: Your code uses requests.get - it is downloading details_of_specific_player.

Comment: Ok so how do you suggest to fix this?